# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I am using xampp and when try to acces the http://localhost i get the "  Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\connect.inc.php on line 2  "

If i remove that php connection everything works just fine. The code for that connection is really simple:

```
<?php
$link =  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'Bbase') or die('Error connecting to database');
?>
```

Also everything worked fine earlier today.

Tried so far: reinstalling xampp, turning apache off and on, restarting pc.

Comment: Did you checked that MySql module is turned on?

Comment: if you are referring to the one in the xampp control panel then yes, it is running.

Comment: Can you access it with: `localhost/phpmyadmin` ?

Comment: yes, i can access phpmyadmin and see other dbs, run sql querries, etc

Comment: Try to put this line in front of your connection: `set_time_limit(120);` does that works for you?

Comment: yes, the page eventually loaded, but surely it shouldn't take so long for it to load.Moreover, i've been working on this project for a while now and i've never had any problems and the page loaded instantly.

Comment: I think then it is a server problem and the better site for this would be here: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: i am doing this on my laptop on win 8.1 pro. Thanks anyway, i'll check that site out

Comment: @Rizier123 No, this doesn't belong on [sf].

Comment: @MichaelHampton SO is about coding, but i don't see any error in the code, i think it's a server problem, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Rizier123 Maybe it belongs on [su] then? But before you send people to a site, I recommend you have some idea of what's on topic at that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Replacing `'localhost'` in

```
<?php
$link =  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'Bbase') or die('Error connecting to database');
?>
```

with `'127.0.0.1'` solved the problem, i'm not entirely sure why but the problem never occurred after doing that.